# Logstash data filter won´t match date in message

Tags: date, filter, logstash

I can't get a match on this message with the date filter

```
"message" => "10.60.1.251\t\"10.60.1.152\"\t2016-12-28\t22:53:50\tPOST\t200\t1014\t0.084\
```

> the message as it is displayed on stdout. The logfile where the message originates from is tab separated "\t"

any suggestions?

I have tried:

```
match => ["message", "YYYY-MM-dd    HH:mm:ss"]
```

> space between date and time is a tab

```
match => ["message", "YYYY-MM-dd'\t'HH:mm:ss"]
match => ["message", "YYYY-MM-dd\tHH:mm:ss"]
match => ["message", "YYYY-MM-dd..HH:mm:ss"]
match => ["message", "YYYY-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss"]
```

and several others

I came up with this solution - not very elegant though

```
filter {
grok { 
    match => ["message","%{DATE:extractDate}    %{HAPROXYTIME:extractTime}"]
}
mutate {
    add_field => {"dateTime" => "20%{extractDate} %{extractTime}"
    }
    remove_field => ["extractDate", "extractTime"]
}

date {
    locale => "en"
    match => ["dateTime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    timezone => "Europe/Vienna"
    target => "@timestamp"
    add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched "}
    remove_field => ["dateTime"]
}
```

}

Comment: According to filter documentation, `"YYYY-MM-dd'\t'HH:mm:ss"` should work. It didn't work for me, and I had to use the workaround you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date{} filter is expecting a pattern that matches the entire string passed in.

The correct flow is to map the fields (as in your grok example), and then send just the date/time fields to the date{} filter.

With tab-separated data, I would look at the csv{} filter, which provides a "separator" parameter that I believe can be set to a tab.

Comment: I will try the csv[] filter. :-)